# Cannot find reference 'pack' in 'None'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to make a basic pong game and starting by drawing a rectangle on the left side of the screen. When I run it i get the error of Cannot find reference 'pack' in 'None'. Thoughts?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('600x600')

canvas_width, canvas_height = 10,100
x1, y1 = canvas_width // 2, canvas_height // 2
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height).place(x=1,y=0)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove .place(x=1,y=0)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `place` from your `canvas`. The issue is that `place()` returns `None`, so your `canvas` object evaluates to `None`. You don't need `place()` if you're going to use `pack()`.

Use one or the other (I prefer `pack()`) - and it's always a good idea to declare your widgets on one line, then add them to a geometry manager on another because, again, the geometry manager functions return `None` and you probably don't want that.

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

*OR*

```
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.place(x=1, y=0)
```